# Cypher - Add multiple connections

Tags: cypher

I have 2 nodes:

Students   and Subjects.

I want to be able to add multiple student names to multiple subjects at the same time using cypher query.
So far I have done it by iterating through the list of names of students and subjects and executing the query for each. but is there a way to do the same in the query itself?

This is the query I use for adding 1 student to 1 subject:

```
 MATCH 
 (s:Student)-[:STUDENT_BELONGS_TO]->(c:Classroom),
 (u:Subjects)-[:SUBJECTS_TAUGHT_IN]->(c:Classroom)
  WHERE
   s.id = ${"$"}studentId
   AND c.id = ${"$"}classroomId
   AND u.name = ${"$"}subjectNames
   AND NOT (s)-[:IN_SUBJECT]->(u)
   CREATE (s)-[:IN_SUBJECT]->(u)
```

So I want to be able to receive multiple subjectNames and studentIds at once to create these connections. Any guidance for multi relationships in cypher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is UNWIND. If you have an array as parameter to your query:

```
studentList :
[
  studentId: "sid1", classroomId: "cid1",  subjectNames: ['s1','s2'] },
  studentId: "sid2", classroomId: "cid2",  subjectNames: ['s1','s3'] },
  ...
]
```

You can UNWIND that parameter in the beginning of your query:

```
UNWIND $studentList as student
MATCH
  (s:Student)-[:STUDENT_BELONGS_TO]->(c:Classroom),
  (u:Subjects)-[:SUBJECTS_TAUGHT_IN]->(c:Classroom)
WHERE
  s.id = student.studentId
AND c.id = student.classroomId
AND u.name = in student.subjectNames
AND NOT (s)-[:IN_SUBJECT]->(u)
CREATE (s)-[:IN_SUBJECT]->(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use **`UNWIND`**.

I haven't tested the code, but something like this might work:

```
MATCH 
    (s:Student)-[:STUDENT_BELONGS_TO]->(c:Classroom),
    (u:Subjects)-[:SUBJECTS_TAUGHT_IN]->(c:Classroom)
WITH
    s AS student, COLLECT(u) AS subjects
UNWIND subjects AS subject
CREATE (student)-[:IN_SUBJECT]->(subject)
```